# Duplicate rows in View MVC EF6

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am getting duplicate rows in my view. I want a view that displays all data for a user (Email, phone, Address). When I click on a user that has two distinct addresses, phone numbers, and emails, I end up with 8 things in my list, so 8 objects of my viewmodel.

Here is how I query the database.

```
public ActionResult View_All(int? id)
        {
            var cape = from c in db.Constituent
                       join ca in db.ConstituentAddress on c.ConstituentId equals ca.ConstituentId
                       join cp in db.ConstituentPhone on c.ConstituentId equals cp.ConstituentId
                       join ce in db.ConstituentEmail on c.ConstituentId equals ce.ConstituentId
                       where ca.ConstituentId == id
                          && c.ConstituentId == id
                          && cp.ConstituentId == id
                          && ce.ConstituentId == id
                       select new ConstituentDetailsView
                       {
                           zConstituent = c,
                           zConstituentAddress = ca,
                           zAddress = ca.Address,
                           zConstituentEmail = ce,
                           zEmail = ce.Email,
                           zConstituentPhone = cp,
                           zPhone = cp.Phone
                       };
            return View("ConstituentDetails/View_All", cape);
        }
```

VIEW:

```
@model IEnumerable<CodeFirstShenanigansWeb.Models.ConstituentDetailsView>

@{


 ViewBag.Title = "View All";
}

<h2>Details</h2>

   <h3>@Model.ElementAt(0).zConstituent.FirstName @Model.ElementAt(0).zConstituent.LastName</h3>
<h4>@Model.Count();</h4>

<h2><b>Addresses</b></h2>

@foreach (var item in Model)
{ 
<div>
    <div>@item.zAddress.Street</div>
    <div>@item.zAddress.City</div>
    <div>@item.zAddress.State</div>
    <div>@item.zAddress.Zip</div>
</div>

}
<h2><b>Phone Numbers</b></h2>   

@foreach (var item in Model)
{

    <div>
        <div>@item.zPhone.Number</div>
    </div>

}

<h2><b>Email Addresses</b></h2>

@foreach (var item in Model)
{

    <div>
        <div>@item.zEmail.Mail</div>
    </div>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "EditAll", new { id = item.zConstituent.ConstituentId})|
    @Ajax.ActionLink("Delete", "DELETE", new { id = item.zConstituent.ConstituentId }, new AjaxOptions

                                                                                      {

                                                                                          Confirm = "Are you sure you want to delete?",

                                                                                          OnComplete = "deleteComplete",

                                                                                          HttpMethod = "DELETE"

                                                                                      })
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")|
</p>
}
```

ViewModel:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using CRM.DomainClasses.Enums;
using CRM.DomainClasses;

namespace CodeFirstShenanigansWeb.Models
{
    public class ConstituentDetailsView
    {
        public Constituent zConstituent { get; set; }
        public Address zAddress { get; set; }
        public Phone zPhone { get; set; }
        public Email zEmail { get; set; }
        public ConstituentPhone zConstituentPhone { get; set; }
        public ConstituentEmail zConstituentEmail { get; set; }
        public ConstituentAddress zConstituentAddress { get; set; }

    }
}
```

I am thinking I need a ViewModel more along these lines:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using CRM.DomainClasses;

namespace CodeFirstShenanigansWeb.Models
{
    public class ConstituentListDetailsView
    {
        public Constituent zConstituent { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Address> zAddress { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Phone> zPhone { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Email> zEmail { get; set; }
        public ConstituentPhone zConstituentPhone { get; set; }
        public ConstituentEmail zConstituentEmail { get; set; }
        public ConstituentAddress zConstituentAddress { get; set; }
    }
```

}
I appreciate any help. Thank you!

Comment: Your code looks correct. Are you sure this query is return a single row and that you don't have perhaps a join that is giving you extra rows? Also, you probably only need one of your four where conditions.

Comment: Is not better to create special View for that case? And you will simplify your LINQ.

Comment: To be clear, my SQL Server Database has no Duplicates, it seems to be different Permutations of the same information. There are two sets of four distinct sub-objects, and since they don't line up, they multiply. I am considering using a child-action approach:http://theshravan.net/blog/child-action-methods-in-asp-net-mvc/